# How to remove the "3D Objects" entry from Windows 10 Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

The 2017 Fall Creators Update to Windows 10 added a "3D Objects" folder to the "This PC" view of Windows Explorer:

[image]

How can this be removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***From:*** [Remove 3D Objects Folder from This PC in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-3d-objects-folder-pc-windows-10/)

Copy these lines to Notepad and save the file with .REG extension (`3dobjects.reg`)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]
```

Double-click the REG file to run it.

This removes 3D Objects shell folder from This PC.

Comment: Is there any way it can be hidden or removed on a machine where you don't have the permission to edit the registry?

Comment: @JonnyWizz: Yes. Follow method 1 in that article if you're using a limited user account.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this blog post](https://www.askvg.com/tip-remove-3d-objects-from-windows-10-explorer-this-pc/) you can remove it by modifying the registry.

For **both** of these keys:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace

You'll see a key with GUID `0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A`.

[image]

Remove it (or rename it, as shown) and then restart explorer.exe and the entry will disappear from Windows Explorer.

If for some reason you get into 3D and want that shortcut back, just remove the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/331361/how-to-remove-the-3d-objects-folder-from-this-pc-on-windows-10/

If you don’t feel like editing the registry, you can download the reg files provided by the HowToGeek.com. Using that, you can remove the “3D Objects” folder as well as restore it.

https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Remove-3D-Objects-Folder.zip

[image: HowToGeek.com - Image]

<sup>**Disclaimer**

Please, use this register files at your own risk. As Drew Noakes commented out, you should read the contents of any register files you download from the internet before using it. I shall not be held liable to and shall not accept any liability, obligation or responsibility whatsoever for any damage caused through use of these downloaded register files.</sup>

Comment: Be sure to read the contents of any `.reg` file you download off the internet before running it.