# Remove items from navigation bar of File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I try to use Windows 10 via `Parallels Desktop` in my new Mac.

In the `File Explorer` of `Windows 10`, I see the following sidebar. Does anyone know how to remove `3D Objects` and `Movies` from there?

[image]

Comment: That side bar is a file tree listing of existing folders. If you want to get rid of them you need to delete the folders.

Comment: It's not very practical then...

Comment: [How to remove the "3D Objects" entry from Windows 10 Explorer? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1262586/how-to-remove-the-3d-objects-entry-from-windows-10-explorer?rq=1) <= that registry edit also removes 3D Objects from the nav pane.